# A problem on estimability of parameters.

Tags: statistics, estimation

> Let $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ and $Y_4$ be four random variables such that $E(Y_1)=\theta_1-\theta_3;\space\space E(Y_2)=\theta_1+\theta_2-\theta_3;\space\space E(Y_3)=\theta_1-\theta_3;\space\space E(Y_4)=\theta_1-\theta_2-\theta_3$, where $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ are unknown parameters. Also assume that $Var(Y_i)=\sigma^2$, $i=1,2,3,4.$ Then which one is true?
>
> > A. $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ are estimable.
> >
> > B. $\theta_1+\theta_3$ is estimable.
> >
> > C. $\theta_1-\theta_3$ is estimable and $\dfrac{1}{2}(Y_1+Y_3)$ is the best linear unbiased estimate of $\theta_1-\theta_3$.
> >
> > D. $\theta_2$ is estimable.

The answer is given is C which looks strange to me (because I got D).

**Why I got D?** Since, $E(Y_2-Y_4)=2\theta_2$.

**Why I don't understand that C could be an answer?** Ok, I can see, $\dfrac{Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+Y_4}{4}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta_1-\theta_3$, and its' variance is less than $\dfrac{Y_1+Y_3}{2}$.

Please tell me where am I doing wrong. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Also posted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319117/a-problem-on-estimability-of-parameters

---

I recently reviewed the question and their is nothing written about $Y_i$'s being uncorrelated. So, please assume that $Y_i$'s are uncorrelated. Please!

Comment: No need to answer anymore, [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319117/a-problem-on-estimability-of-parameters/319171#319171) has already provided 3 of them.